# How to Display a combobox message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for some help or advice. I am trying to put a message in a combo box prompting the user to make a selection. Everything thing I've read has told be to use `this.comboboxname.Text = "Message"`,

however I have tried this in a few different places and it dose not seem to work in my code.

I'm wondering if i have missed something blatantly obvious. Any suggestions?

Code:

```
namespace DatabaseConnection
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this dosen't work
        this.worldCbx.Text = "Select a Country";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=>This works fine.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM bbc", con);
        SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            this.worldCbx.Items.Add(sdr["name"]);
        }
        sdr.Close();
    }
    private void worldCbx_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this dosen't work either.  
        this.worldCbx.Text = "Select a Country";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comboBox.Text = “Select A Country” basically will set the selection of the comboBox to “Select A Country” IF it exist in the Items list. So if you have a comboBox where the items are…

Select A Country

USA

Russia

Canada

Mexico

Then the command comboBox.Text = “Select A Country” will set the comboBox’s selected value to “Select A Country” because it IS an item in the comboBox's Items. To get the comboBox to act as you describe… use the code below.

However, the problem with this approach is that once you select a country, the comboBox will immediately return to “Select A Country.” So the user may forget what they just selected or may not be sure. Either way, from a user standpoint this can be confusing.

It sounds like a simple label "Select A Country" above the comboBox would be a better solution. Hope this helps.

```
comboBox1.Items.Add("Select A Country");
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
  comboBox1.Items.Add("Country_" + i);
}
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // do something with the selected index
  // - then reset the comboBox to "Select a country
  this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
  comboBox1.Text = "Select A Country";
  this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Your example did what I needed it to do but as you described it can be confusing for the end user. I think I was trying to make this more complicated that necessary and a simple label will do the job just as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @cdjd44 You are welcome. I do the same thing, simplifying things can be a challenge. I call it coding myopia where you get so focused on an approach that you forget about the end result. Good Luck.